# File delete audit, Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, security, event-log

I have a shared folder (folderA) and our users must copy some files everyday and after they finish working they have to delete files and when they delete files there must be a record.(for security resons).

I order to keep record for file delete procces. I enable auditing from local security policies and on folderA, properies/security/advanced/audit add success entry for everyone. if someone delete a existing file triggers event id:4663 and i can record.

But it works for only existing files and files which created inside the folder. if a user delete a copied file from elsewhere, event id:4663 don't trigger. is anyone can tell me, am I doing something wrong? or maybe there is another way?

Comment: A copied file from their local machines?  It sounds like you only enabled this policy on the machine where the shared drive is physically installed.  If you want to audit the removal of copies that involves enabling the policy on all machines.

Comment: I am testing before put in service. so i create a file on my desktop and move it to auidit enabled folder and delete but event viewer dont trigger id:4663

Comment: You should clarify your question.  I thought you were saying something different entirely

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I didn't think that all machines needed to enable auditing. but thanks if I figur out current problem, I will enable the policy on all machines.